# How Can I Override Style Info from a CSS Class in the Body of a Page?

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a project that accepts HTMLs as inputs and returns them as outputs. All of the HTMLs I get as inputs have all of their text in divs and style sheets that dictate the style for each div based on the class attribute.

To better visualize things, and to see how my project is coming along, I would love to output the input HTMLs color coded to specifications I give them. It's really easy for me to modify the body of the HTML, but difficult to deal with the style sheet. All I'm looking for is something simple to override the color property of the style sheet. It can be hacky, as this is just internal code for temporary use. I just want something simple that works. Is there an easy way to override aspects of CSS classes in the body of a file?

[EDIT] I want to provide an example to better explain what I'm looking for. An example of the style sheets I have at the top of my page (that I want to override) is:

`.style21{vertical-align:top;font-size:13px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}`

An example of a div whose color I'd like to change is:

`<div style="position:absolute;top:432;left:422;color:#ff0000;"><span class="style21">relating to</span></div>`

My problem is that I can't override the color specified in the css. As you can see in the above example, I'm trying to do it in the specific style within the div, but that isn't working. [/EDIT]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Either use the style attribute to add CSS inline on your divs, e.g.:

```
<div style="color:red"> ... </div>
```

... or create your own style sheet and reference it after the existing stylesheet then your style sheet should take precedence.

... or add a `<style>` element in the `<head>` of your HTML with the CSS you need, this will take precedence over an external style sheet.

You can also add `!important` after your style values to override other styles on the same element.

**Update**

Use one of my suggestions above and target the span of class style21, rather than the containing div. The style you are applying on the containing div will not be inherited by the span as it's color is set in the style sheet.

Answer (score 31):

- Id's are prior to classnames.
- Tag attribue 'style=' is prior to CSS selectors.
- `!important` word is prior to first two rules.
- More specific CSS selectors are prior to less specific.
  More specific will be applied.

for example:

- `.divclass .spanclass` is more specific than `.spanclass`
- `.divclass.divclass` is more specific than `.divclass`
- `#divId .spanclass` has ID that's why it is more specific than `.divClass .spanClass`
- `<div id="someDiv" style="color:red;">` has attribute and beats `#someDiv{color:blue}`
- style: `#someDiv{color:blue!important}` will be applied over attribute `style="color:red"`

Comment: I never thought that this also affects to the style order applying!

Answer (score 2):

you can test a color by writing the CSS inline like `<div style="color:red";>...</div>`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is what I originally tried, but it doesn't seem to override the css, which is what led me to posting here. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Hussein, I would guess it's because I answered his question ;-)

Comment: @graham, I understand, you even copied the dots i had inside the div.

Comment: @eli didn't even give the change for me to check his comment and answer him back about adding the !important tag. This answer should deserve the check. No offense to you graham.

Comment: @hussein i agree. @eli, you should consider giving the check to whoever gave the same answer first.

Comment: @hussein sorry I didn't realise you had invented the ellipsis. The comment eli posted on my answer tells you the update I made to my answer was what lead him to a solution.

Comment: @graham no offense but you even choose the color property and the red color in addition to the 3 dots. Maybe a coincidence ??.... Anyhow, i just wanted to give @eli the note. You did not need to reply to my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can put CSS in the `head` of the HTML file, and it will take precedent over a class in an included style sheet.

```
<style>
.thing{
    color: #f00;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the !important flag on the style?  !important allows you to decide which style will win out.  Also note !important will override inline styles as well.

```
#example p {
    color: blue !important;
}
...
#example p {
    color: red;
}
```

Another couple suggestions:

Add a span inside of the current.  The inner most will win out.  Although this could get pretty ugly.

```
<span class="style21">
<span style="position:absolute;top:432px;left:422px; color:Red" >relating to</span>
</span>
```

jQuery is also an option. The jQuery library will inject the style attribute in the targeted element.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("span").css("color", "#ff0000");
        });

    </script>
```

Hope this helps. CSS can be pretty frustrating at times.

Comment: Can you place the styles inside of the element you want to override as opposed to wrapping them in another element?  I just recreated the example above and the !important would not work but adding the style directly to the span tag does.  <span class="style21" style="color:#ff0000;">

Answer (score 0):

if you can access the head add
`<style>
/*...some style */
</style>`
 the way Hussein showed you
and the ultra hacky
`<style>
</style>`
in the html it will work but its ugly.
or javascript it the best way if you can use it in you case

Answer (score 0):

Eli,
it is important to remember that in css specificity goes a long way. If your inline css is using the !important and isn't overriding the imported stylesheet rules then closely observe the code using a tool such as 'firebug' for firefox. It will show you the css being applied to your element. If there is a syntax error firebug will show you in the warning panel that it has thrown out the declaration.

Also remember that in general an id is more specific than a class is more specific than an element.

Hope that helps.

-Rick