# Use same named class from different css file

Tags: html, css

I want to use a class. The problem is I have two CSS files containing that same named class one in first.css and another in second.css my order of linking the css files is like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="adminlte.css" />
```

adminlte.css is used for my interface but I like the look of the bootstrap forms. Whenever I call the class form-control it is styled by adminlte.css.

How can I call the class form-control but use the one from Bootstrap?

Note: I cannot switch the order of linking the css files.

Comment: if you cant change the order then it will always use the 2nd styles, thats how it works.

Comment: Look at "[What does `!important` in CSS mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean) on this very site.

Comment: sounds like you have some fundamental css architecture issues.  do you or do you not have control over the css?

Comment: what is the reason to have the same class in two files? What is the purpose of the two different files?

Comment: Delete the class from adminlte.css...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Override Style Info from a CSS Class in the Body of a Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382254/how-can-i-override-style-info-from-a-css-class-in-the-body-of-a-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify which version of a class rule to use except by load order or by specificity. Since Bootstrap uses standalone (not nested or stacked) selectors, you can't compound class selectors to increase specificity. This leaves local overrides as your only recourse.

Grab the CSS block from the library file and drop it into your document using a `style` tag:

```
<style>
    .form-control {
        ...
    }

</style>
```

Embedded styles override linked stylesheets, so even though the selectors are identical this one takes precedence.

Answer (score -1):

Would `@media` queries eliminate the need for two stylesheets?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    #my_div{
        /* style */
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:769px){
    #my_div{
        /* style */
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry it would not

Answer (score -1):

As you written one question below your main question about !important if you see this thing in second css which is overwriting your first one.

Because !important will always overwrite normal css.

as you didn't mention exact thing i will suggest you to take first link after second one and which element css you want to apply give that properties !important like below example. below given is just example not your exact need it's just to explain you how it works.

```
.example{
    font-size: 16px !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the OP mention `!important`, but it should be a very last resort.