# Override css class in Angular

Tags: css

I have following HTML for table and CSS

HTML

```
<table *ngIf="tableRows.length > 0" class="design-table table-hover">
```

CSS

```
.design-table {
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 0 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

I wonder how to change `border-spacing` to `4 4px` without changing `.design-table` CSS because it is being used many other places.

Comment: Have you tried to add it as an inline style?

Comment: how can it be done?

Comment: By using the `style` attribute.

Comment: could u please give an example?

Comment: If you control the classes (`"design-table table-hover"`) could you not add another class (e.g. `extraPadding`), and then add the style in there? e.g. `.design-table.extraPadding{}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Override Style Info from a CSS Class in the Body of a Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382254/how-can-i-override-style-info-from-a-css-class-in-the-body-of-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it maybe like other CSS frameworks do it. For instance, in Bulma, you have a class, say `button` and if you want to change it's look, you add another class like `is-primary` or `is-danger`etc.

If you can edit the HTML in your code, or modify it during runtime, you can always make a more specific CSS selector:

HTML

```
<table *ngIf="tableRows.length > 0" class="design-table special-border table-hover">
```

CSS

```
.design-table {
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 0 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.design-table.special-border {
    border-spacing: 4px 4px;
}
```